# Object animation in Powerpoint 2010 on mouse click or mouse over

Tags: animation

I have simple two rectangle shapes in powerpopint 2010 I want to make it size bigger or any kind of animation when user move mouse on it on mouse click,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, see [Mouse Over Images](http://www.pptworkbench.com/html/mouse_over_images.htm).

> It is very easy to change images by mouse over, say from a color one to grayscale. A color image on Slide One will change to a grayscale image on Slide Two, using a mouse over Action Setting.